# Can't Access XML data externally using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I cannot access the content of an xml file using the AJAX code bellow. However, it works just fine when I try to access the file when it is stored locally, on my computer. I am trying to pull data from this xml file to generate my own countdown. Please advise.

Here is my code:

```
// Reading from .xml 
    //
    $(document).ready(function()
    {                           
        function loadfail(){
            alert("Error: Failed to read file!");
        }

        function load_date(document){
            $(document).find("countdown").each(function(){
                var $date       = $(this);
                var $day        = $date.find('startdays').text();
                var $hours      = $date.find('starthours').text();
                var $minutes    = $date.find('startminutes').text();
                var $seconds    = $date.find('startseconds').text();

                $('.day').text($day);
                $('.hours').text($hours);
                $('.minutes').text($minutes);
                $('.seconds').text($seconds);

                $('#counter').countdown({
                    image: 'images/digits.png',
                    //startTime: '1:12:12:00'
                    startTime: $day + ':' + $hours + ':' + $minutes + ':' + $seconds,
                });
            });
        }

        $.ajax({
            //url: 'date.xml',    // name of file with our data
            //url: 'http://localhost/countdown02/date.xml',    // name of file with our data
            url: 'http://website.com/dev_kit/date.xml',    // name of file with our data
            dataType: 'xml',    // type of file we will be reading
            success: load_date,     // name of function to call when done reading file
            error: loadfail     // name of function to call when failed to read
        });

    });
```

Comment: In your `loadfail` function, output the three arguments that get passed. They will help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Is the xml file on another domain than the js-script?

Comment: @Louis Yes, the xml is on another domain than the js-script. That is my dilemma.

Comment: @Jasper I will try that. I'm still new to jQuery. Thanks

Comment: Well there's your problem. That's called a cross domain request, which won't work without additional work. There are several possibilities: CORS, JSONP, serverside proxies. Google it, you might find a solution suitable to you.

Comment: @Louis I will definitely do that. Which of the methods above do you recommend?

Comment: Depends on your possibilities. If you have access to the other domain, I would try CORS, if not a serverside proxy would probably be the easiest (Have a serverside script on your domain call the url with a normal http request and use that script for your ajax request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't truly a jQuery answer to this question, however, it gets the job done. Since I am developing this site in php I am merely going to copy the xml file from the host server and copy it to a local directory for access. Here is the solution that I am using without sanitation, etc.

```
<?php 
$file = 'http://website.com/dev_kit/date.xml';
$newfile = './date.xml';

if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
    echo "Copy success!";
}else{
    echo "Copy failed.";
}
?>
```

Many thanks to those of you who took the time to help me.